# UIWebView - how to extract the HTML code from webpages like Facebook?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, xcode, uiwebview

i have an example of a source code which programatically sets the value of fields in an HTML.

The part of the source code is as such:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

myWebView.delegate = self;

//---formulate the HTML string---
NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:
                @"<html>"
                 "    <body>"
                 "        <h1>The fields below are filled in programmatically</h1>"
                 "        <input id='username' value='UserName' />"
                 "        <input id='password' value='Password' type='password' />"
                 "    </body>"
                 "</html>"
                 ] autorelease];

//---load the UIWebView with the html string---
[myWebView loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];
}

//---wait for the UIWebView to finish loading---
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
//---access the 2 fields in the HTML---
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('username').value='Wei-Meng Lee';"];
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('password').value='TopSecret';"];
}
```

I would like to programmatically set value of fields in an actually webpage like Facebook instead of a custom HTML like such written above.

How should i replace the "str" to an actual webpage's html source code so that i can pick out the "ElementbyId"?

Comment: You are looking for opening a web page from a URL instead of HTML ?

Comment: i want to open a webpage from a URL and be able to use the stringByEvaulatingJavaScriptFromString function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by replacing

```
//---formulate the HTML string---
NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:
            @"<html>"
             "    <body>"
             "        <h1>The fields below are filled in programmatically</h1>"
             "        <input id='username' value='UserName' />"
             "        <input id='password' value='Password' type='password' />"
             "    </body>"
             "</html>"
             ] autorelease];

//---load the UIWebView with the html string---
[myWebView loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];
```

with `[UIWebView loadRequest]` and it will load the web view with the URL and the UIWebView will contain the HTML to make `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` work.